# Why can't helium nuclei (alpha particles) react with fluorine?

Tags: noble-gases

Alpha particles are basically just helium nuclei, so it will accept an electron pair to become stable.

Will fluorine, being highly electronegative, not just donate an electron pair but form a bond with helium?

Comment: So are you asking about the existence of $\ce{HeF2}$?

Comment: Don't confuse the extreme *nuclear* stability of the $\cf{^4He}$ nucleus, i.e., an alpha particle, with the *electronic* stability of naked $\cf{He2+}$ cations.

Comment: Nobody said a word about $\ce{He}_2^+$; as for $\ce{He}^{2+}$, it is of course electronically stable, as it has no electrons at all.

Comment: @marcus - Please edit your question for clarity and content. As it stands, it's very unclear what you are asking and might get closed.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt I am just trying to ask why cant alpha particles react with fluorine atoms?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I couldnt undertand how could He^2+ be electronically stable?

Comment: Sorry Ivan, I made a typo and of course meant $\cf{He^{2+}}$.  It is not electronically stable at all, at least not for definitions of electronically stable I am familiar with.

Comment: How could it _not_ be? Imagine a lone alpha particle deep in outer space; how is it unstable? What would happen to it, electronically or otherwise? (Sorry, just kidding.)

Comment: @marcus - I have edited your post to reflect your comment.

Comment: @marcus Can you clarify exactly what molecules/ions you are thinking about. $\ce{HeF2}$, $\ce{HeF^2+}$ or something else?

Comment: @bon Actually i am not thinking about any ions or molecules as i searched and found them to just not exist. I am thinking WHY couldnt they exist? Fluorine is very electronegative and if alpha particles are projected into a fluorine environment, surely they will attract the electrons of fluorine. But it would be really tough for fluorine to give up its electrons and so a covalent or a dative bond might be formed. Since they do not, i really want to know why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why, many atoms would readily create a bond with helium, when it comes in a form of alpha particle (just cooled down enough to chemically interact with). There is comparatively stable [$\ce{HeH}^+$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_hydride_ion) and other similar particles, too. But a positive particle is not a compound yet. And when you try to form a compound out of it, that is, to balance it with some negative ions - well, that's where the problem arises. It would violently react with absolutely anything else, form some compound, and happily release the neutral helium atom.

Comment: Thats why i asked what if alpha particles were to form bonds with fluorine? In a case like that the alpha particles couldn't just take away the electrons of fluorine and leave a positively charged fluorine?

Comment: Of course it can. The ionization energy of helium is by far the largest among all elements, so it will take electrons from anything. A covalent bond may be formed, too; I expect a particle like $\ce{HeF}^+$ to appear, which would be stable for just as long as it doesn't encounter anything negatively charged.

Comment: You mean as long as long as it does not encounter anything, except another Helium atom, right?

Comment: I said "negatively charged". Come to think of it, most neutral particles (except another helium atom, you are right on that) would react with it just as well. Positive ions, though, probably would not.

Answer (score 1):

> Will fluorine, being highly electronegative, not just donate an electron pair but form a bond with helium?

Yes a fluorine atom and helium atom can form a "molecule" $\ce{HeF}$. Such a molecule would be very unstable chemically. Two such molecules bumping into to one another would yield helium atoms and fluorine molecules.

An alpha particle is an "energetic" bare helium nucleus. Think of the speed that a fluorine molecule would be moving in fluorine gas. The charged alpha particle is traveling much much faster so it is ripping through the gas bumping into fluorine molecules thus creating ions and free electrons. So in fluorine gas as the alpha particle slows down it forms a helium atom. Thus overall you'd get uncharged helium atoms and $\ce{F2+}$ ions.